# JAVA - How to sort a LIST of OBJECT using comparator by comparing muliplte values inside a LIST

Tags: java, list, sorting, comparator

I have question regarding Java Comparator. Or maybe you all have another Idea to solve this problems.

I have object called Product, below the Product Class looks like:

```
public class Product(){
   private String productId;
   private List categoryList;

   //...setter and getter for category List
}
```

Then I have a list of Product, List. And I want to sort the list based on the category of Product:

Here example of the List:

```
{
    Product = {
        productId:10000567,
        categoryList: {1002, 1003, 1007}
    },
    Product = {
        productId:10000568,
        categoryList: {1001, 1003, 1007}
    },
    Product = {
        productId:10000569,
        categoryList: {1001, 1004, 1007}
    },
    Product = {
        productId:10000570,
        categoryList: {1004, 1005, 1007}
    }
}
```

I already try to use comparator, but I only can compare one value for one time.
Thanks for your response.

Comment: Which list are you trying to sort? The list of Products or the list of categories? If it is the list of Products, what determines if one Product is before or after another Product? The number of categories? the minimum category id? The maximum category id, the sum of category ids? The smallest number of categories after removing the common categories?... I think you get my point.

Comment: What does your current comparator look like?

Comment: for p1 category list is {1002, 1003, 1007}
for p2 it is {1001, 1004, 1007}
What product should be the first and why? How do you want to compare lists?

Comment: @RogerLindsjö I want to sort the list of Products based on the List of categories. I actually have the answer already. Thomas inspired me to do so. But I still cannot answer because my reputation below 1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let your class Product implement the interface Comparable, then implement compareTo(), then sort the List with Collections.sort(myList);

```
public class Product implements Comparable<Product>{
   private String productId;
   private List categoryList;

  //...setter and getter for category List

   public int compareTo(Product p) {
       //return -1, 0 or 1 based on what you decide makes p to be less than this
   }

}

//sort it
java.util.Collections.sort(myProductList);
```

Comment: Hi, Thomas. Thanks for ur response. Of course I already do thi comparator class. But, if you can see, it will only compare one value in category list for each product. Get what I mean. When you called this comparator class, it will only compare product1.categoryList.get(0) with product2.categoryList.get(0). Meanwhil I need to sort based on all category inside categoryList.

Comment: Yes, but you need to write compareTo to return -1, 0 or 1 based on what is contained in your category list. If the content of category list should decide the order of your products, you must implement compareTo() in Product to do this.

Should your products be sorted based on the sum of the content in the categoryList? Should it be sorted based on the first category element, the last?

Comment: The issue here is that Producs have a many - many relation to Categories. One product can be in many categories, and a category can have many products.

Comment: Yes, the issue is that. The object is many-to-many relationship. I already get the answer. I tried to answer this. Thanks BTW

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already tried this, but you could override the [comparable interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and have compare do whatever you want with the values inside the list.

The problem is, of course, that you need to find a consistent comparison algorithm. Can you determine if a product is "bigger" or "smaller" depending on the categories it belongs to? Sorting needs this kind of unambiguous, one-dimensional decision...

Otherwise, it looks like you might want to put things in a database and perform operations on a per category basis

Comment: Yes, I already create a comparator class for this sorting. But, It is not correct I guess. Because it only compare only one category for each product. Unfortunately it cannot be done on database side.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Comparable in Product and use Collections.sort(). You'll have to make the lists Comparable too and use it in Product.compareTo().

Answer (score 0):

Thomas inspired me to solve this problem. The issue is only because I comparing the product based on multiple values. Meaning, the object is many-to-many relationship.

What I do is simple, just write the comparator class to compare the category of the products. THE MAIN KEY is do sorting for each category.

```
ProductCategoryComparator comparator = new ProductCategoryComparator();
for (int i = 1 ; i < catKeyList.size() ; i++){
   comparator.setCategoryKey((String)catKeyList.get(i));
   Collections.sort(productList, comparator);
}
```

Hope this answer can assist everyone that might have similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- you're using Java 8+
- you want to sort by `productId` first, then by `categoryList`
- `categoryList` contains Comparables (e.g. strings or integers)
- `categoryList`s should be compared pairwise (starting with most significant pair) using natural ordering

Then you could use something like this:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    var p1 = new Product("1", List.of(1001, 1003, 1007));
    var p21 = new Product("2", List.of(1002, 1003, 1004));
    var p22 = new Product("2", List.of(1002, 1002, 1003));
    var p23 = new Product("2", List.of(1001, 1002, 1003));
    var p3 = new Product("3", List.of(1001, 1002, 1003));
    var products = new ArrayList<>(List.of(p3, p1, p21, p22, p23));

    Comparator<Product> productIdComparator = Comparator.comparing(product -> product.productId);
    Comparator<Product> combinedComparator = productIdComparator
            .thenComparing(product -> product.categoryList, comparingListElements(3));
    products.sort(combinedComparator);        // result: p1 p21 p22 p23 p3
}

private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<List<T>> comparingListElements(final int listSize) {
    return IntStream.range(0, listSize)
            .mapToObj(index -> Comparator.comparing((List<T> list) -> list.get(index)))
            .reduce(Comparator::thenComparing)
            .orElseThrow();
}
```